# Return JSON object (ASP.NET WebAPI)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET Web API

It returns me JSON like this

`[{"CompanyID":1,"CompanyName":"Тест"},{"CompanyID":5,"CompanyName":"Фокстрот"}]`

As I understood this is Json array, but I need to return JSOn Object instead of it

Like this: `{"results":[{"CompanyID":1,"CompanyName":"Тест"},{"CompanyID":5,"CompanyName":"Фокстрот"}]}`

Here is my GetCompanies controller:

```
public class GetCompaniesController : ApiController
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: api/GetCompanies
    public IQueryable<Companies> GetCompanies()
    {
        return db.Companies;
    }

    // GET: api/GetCompanies/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Companies))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCompanies(int id)
    {
        Companies companies = await db.Companies.FindAsync(id);
        if (companies == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(companies);
    }

    // PUT: api/GetCompanies/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutCompanies(int id, Companies companies)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != companies.CompanyID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(companies).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!CompaniesExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/GetCompanies
    [ResponseType(typeof(Companies))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostCompanies(Companies companies)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Companies.Add(companies);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = companies.CompanyID }, companies);
    }

    // DELETE: api/GetCompanies/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Companies))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteCompanies(int id)
    {
        Companies companies = await db.Companies.FindAsync(id);
        if (companies == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Companies.Remove(companies);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(companies);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool CompaniesExists(int id)
    {
        return db.Companies.Count(e => e.CompanyID == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

How I need to modify my controller?

Thank's

Comment: When using web api, returning `IQuarable` or `IEnumberable` is meaningless and they have no possible advantage. Either use a list or an array. Regarding your question, you need to `wrap` the result (your output).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

When returning a value, try it like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetCompanies()
{
    var companies = db.Companies.ToList();
    return Ok( new { results = companies });
}
```

Comment: For one id it works.

For this ` public IQueryable<Companies> GetCompanies()
        {
            return db.Companies;
        }` 

How I need to do ?