# Web API - Output value

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a web API method which will return a value in the form of as follows

[
    {
        "TransactionId": "AJ978962017",
        "Total": 1.17
    },
    {
        "TransactionId": "AJ978972017",
        "Total": 8.9
    }
]

I want the output without outer array like as follows

{
        "TransactionId": "AJ978962017",
        "Total": 1.17
    },
    {
        "TransactionId": "AJ978972017",
        "Total": 8.9
    }

Kindly suggest how to achieve the desired output.

Code

```
[Authorize]
// ..api/EmpDetails/Id
public IEnumerable<EmpDetail> Get(string Id)
{
    using (WebAPIEntities WE = new WebAPIEntities())
    {
        var emp = WE.TrxDetails.Where(E => E.EmpId == Id).ToList();
        return emp;
    }
}
```

Comment: show the code for your method which returns the array of objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return JSON object (ASP.NET WebAPI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566284/return-json-object-asp-net-webapi)

Comment: [Authorize]
        //..api/EmpDetails/Id
        public IEnumerable<EmpDetail> Get(string Id)
        {
            using (WebAPIEntities WE = new WebAPIEntities())
            {
                var emp = WE.TrxDetails.Where(E => E.EmpId == Id).ToList();

                             
                return emp;
            }
        }

Comment: @Jayakumar I'd advise you to format it and put it into the question body. Also, you're returning an `List<EmpDetail>()`. If you only want one, only return one.

Comment: @John How to return one value. Can you send sample code.

Comment: @Jayakumar As soon as you edit your question :)

Comment: @John I've edited my code

Comment: @Jayakumar I've added an answer which should resolve your issue. Please format your question more like it is now in future questions. This will get better responses from the SO community and won't result in all of these downvotes you've received.

Comment: @John Thanks for your code. But incase if my output return type is list means. Example I'm using the same code for my other Transactiondetails webAPI methods which will return all values in the transaction. In that case how can I remove my outer array. Appreciate your response.

Comment: If you're returning all values (i.e. all records) then you shouldn't typically remove the array declaration. How do you expect multiple records to look? Like this?: `{"name": "Michael"}{"name":"Jordan"}` - I'm not sure something like that is valid JSON.

Comment: @John I have updated my ques for my desired output.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to return it like that?

Comment: Some Transaction have one item / Many items purchase. So if we pass Transaction Id it depends on the sale it will return the items in the above mentioned list

Comment: In that case, I would recommend always returning a proper JSON array, complete with the [square braces]. I'd think it would conform more to how someone would expect the API to work. If you really want to do it that way, then you can look at an `Action Filter` to remove the square braces after serialization. Note that a lot of JSON serializers (including JS' JSON.parse(...)) won't be able to deserialize the array without the square braces.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @John

Answer (score 0):

The Linq extension method `Where(...)` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. Where is a filter on a list, and as such will return a list (`IEnumerable`). You're then calling `ToList()` to convert it into a `List<T>`. When you serialize to JSON, `IEnumerable<T>`, `List<T>`, and `T[]` are all represented (correctly) as a JSON array: [{...}, {...}, {...}]

```
[Authorize]
// ..api/EmpDetails/Id
public IEnumerable<EmpDetail> Get(string Id)
{
    using (WebAPIEntities WE = new WebAPIEntities())
    {
        var emp = WE.TrxDetails.Where(E => E.EmpId == Id).ToList();
        return emp;
    }
}
```

If you only want a single item, there are a few ways you can do this with Linq:

`Single(...)` - This will return a value so long as that value is unique in the list. It will throw an error if it isn't found.

`SingleOrDefault(...)` - This will return a value, or null if it isn't found.

`First(...)` - This will return the first matching value, or throw an error if there aren't any.

`FirstOrDefault(...)` - This will return the first matching value, or null if there aren't any.

`Last(...)` - This will return the last matching value, or throw an error if there aren't any.

`LastOrDefault(...)` - This will return the last matching value, or null if there aren't any.

The exception type returned by the above is: `InvalidOperationException`

I'm assuming `FirstOrDefault(...)` will suffice for your scenario:

```
[Authorize]
// ..api/EmpDetails/Id
public IEnumerable<EmpDetail> Get(string Id)
{
    using (WebAPIEntities WE = new WebAPIEntities())
    {
        return WE.TrxDetails.FirstOrDefault(E => E.EmpId == Id);
    }
}
```